# PySpark: How can I concatenate two different RDD with the same number of rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to concat 2 different dataframes but I was not able to do that at this moment.
I would like to do the following.

user_ids

```
+-------+
|user_id|
+-------+
|  96885|
|  58620|
|  56483|
|  65282|
|  61336|
|  63337|
|  56484|
|  36890|
|  57420|
|  54434|
| 101512|
|  58622|
|  67561|
|  55617|
|  58623|
|  54435|
| 230572|
|  58624|
|  30034|
|  55639|
+-------+
```

prediction

```
+----------+
|prediction|
+----------+
|         1|
|         1|
|         0|
|         0|
|         1|
|         0|
|         1|
|         1|
|         1|
|         1|
|         1|
|         1|
|         0|
|         0|
|         1|
|         1|
|         0|
|         1|
|         1|
|         1|
+----------+
```

What I would like to have is another RDD as following.

```
+-------++----------+
|user_id||prediction|
+-------++----------+
|  96885||         1|
|  58620||         1|
|  56483||         0|
|  65282||         0|
|  61336||         1|
|  63337||         0|
|  56484||         1|
|  36890||         1|
|  57420||         1|
|  54434||         1|
| 101512||         1|
|  58622||         1|
|  67561||         0|
|  55617||         0|
|  58623||         1|
|  54435||         1|
| 230572||         0|
|  58624||         1|
|  30034||         1|
|  55639||         1|
+-------++----------+
```

Using pandas I could do something like

```
user_ids['prediction'] = prediction.
```

But I need to do it in a distributed way using pyspark. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean *"in a distributed way"* ?

Comment: The dataset is too big to be converted to pandas, changed and converted to spark. So I need a way to merge it without convert it to pandas.

Comment: spark can't store a dataframe's ordering as it is distributed in nature. that means, the two dataframes won't align on index as there are no indices in spark. without an index it'd be impossible to concat the 2 dataframes in the way you want.

Comment: @samkart Got it. I'll create a index column with the row number in both the RDD to be able to perform the merge. Thanks